# How to know request.user logged in by facebook account

Tags: django

I have created an application for e commerce. There is option for facebook authentication.I want to check if the user logged in by facebook.Is there any condition to check request.user logged in by facebook?

I have searched google and got one condition but its not working for me

```
{% if request.user.facebookprofile %}user has facebook profile{% endif %}
```

Comment: Are you using some package such as django-facebook? You have to provide more details.

Comment: i am using django allauth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in python

```
def isFacebook(user_id):
    fb_uid = SocialAccount.objects.filter(user_id=self.user.id, provider='facebook')

    return len(fb_uid) != 0
```